# How to convert PCM samples from Microphone to bytes in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, websocket, audio-recording, microphone

I am working on react-native project that reads audio samples from microphone and sends it over websocket for processing.The samples I read are in the following format 258,-403,-595,-740,-643,-595,-836,-1109,-1141,-1317,-1428,-1059,-804,-884,-980,-788,-451,-419,-387,-82,61,157,366,462,446,606,574,478,767,1038,1088,1216,1505,1617,1248,991,1007,751,494,398,221,-50,-419,-690,-788,-948,-1059,-1027,-980,-1027,-1141,-1075,-1093,-1205,-996,-706,-435,-146,29,-162,-338,-178,-50,-162,-322,-499,-531,-306,-18,269,574,863,783,622,558,685,1022,1104,1136,1070,815,606,348,205,61,-274,-611,-852,-884,-675,-595,-611,-483,-242,-66,0,269,430,269,269,398,430,269,125,333,253,-258,-162,45,-338,-627,-371,-98,-146,0,205,109,189,285,366,430,414,382,173,205,414,382,13,-419,-353,-403,-627,-675,-722,-675,-900,-1093,-932,-836,-772,-627,-611,-595,-451,-274,-162,-387,-242,-130,-322,-98,0,-34,237,462,526,462,526,799,895,991,1104,1200,1407,1537,1697,1697,1423,1328,1184,1070,799,221,-194,-531,-884,-996,-1043,-1189,-1173,-1027,-916,-868,-980,-980,-868,-722,-531,-483,-515,-611,-595,-690,-900,-868,-932,-916,-804,-980,-1012,-788,-483,-114,45,45,29,253,478,382,348,510,767,1022,1054,1136,1296,1360,1136,1022,1216,1136,911,767,478

If I write them to file ,they are getting written as it is.How to convert them before dumping them to file, so that I can later play it with Audacity?

Comment: do you find any solution about this ?
i am also trying to do it with react native

Comment: Not yet . I have used a work around by making some changes in RecordingModule.java of react-native-recording module.

Comment: if possible can you please share it.my concept is like walkie talkie..if i speak from one device on other end it will be audible..i am sending data through webSocket

Comment: can you please provide the file you made it

Comment: I have posted the answer , see if it helps .

Comment: Thank you so much..do you know how to play/listen this data on other hand??

Answer (score 1):

Finally , I was able to found a way to do it.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state={
      status:true
    }

  }
  componentDidMount() {

    ws = new WebSocket('ws://192.168.0.2:1234');

    ws.onopen=()=>{
      console.log('Opened')
    }

    ws.onerror=(e)=>{
      console.log(e.message)
    }

    ws.onmessag=(e)=>{
      console.log(e.data);
    }
    ws.onclose=()=>{
      console.log('closed')
    }

    //Recording.start()

  }

  startVoice(){

    Recording.init({
      bufferSize: 640,
      sampleRate: 16000,
      bitsPerChannel: 16,
      channelsPerFrame: 1,
    })

    const listener = Recording.addRecordingEventListener(data => {

      //console.log(data)
      var view = new Uint16Array(data);
      ws.send(view);

    })

    Recording.start();
    this.setState({status:false});
  }

  stopVoice(){
    Recording.stop();
    this.setState({status:true});
  }

componentWillUnmount() {
    //Recording.stop()
  }

  render() {
    return(
        <View>
       {this.state.status?<Button title='start' onPress={()=>this.startVoice()}/>:<Button title='stop' onPress={()=>this.stopVoice()}/>}
       </View>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thank you so much..do you know how to play/listen the data which i sent via WebSocket on other hand?

Comment: If you simply want to verify ,you can dump the data to file on the other side and later can play it with Audacity tool. If you want to play it using react-native ,you can check existing modules like react-native-pcm-audio .. etc

Comment: Is it possible to convert this Unit16Array to base64 and then write the file to check that file is playable or what ?